# Does Julia have a string 'contains' substring method?

Tags: string, julia

I am trying to test whether or not a string contains a specific substring and then if it does, the index at which it occurs. How can I do that in Julia?

Answer (score 29, accepted):

Julia has a couple of helpful functions that will let you do what a traditional 'contains' function would do.

`occursin()` takes two arguments. The first of which is the substring you are looking for and the second being the target or string you will be searching in.

`findfirst()` takes the same arguments but this time returns the index of the first occurrence of the substring if it's found.

```
julia> a = "HelloWorld"
"HelloWorld"

julia> occursin("Hello", a)
true

julia> findfirst("Hello", a)
1:5
```

See the Julia docs [here](https://docs.julialang.org/en/v1/base/strings/#Base.findfirst-Tuple%7BAbstractString,AbstractString%7D) for more reading on `findfirst()` or [here](https://docs.julialang.org/en/v1/base/strings/#Base.occursin) for `occursin()`.

Comment: also worth nothing both functions also take regular expressions rather than just substrings. eg `occursin(r"H\w+?o", a)` and `findfirst(r"H\w+?o", a)`

Answer (score 2):

While there isn't (at my knowledge) a Julia function to return the index of all the occurrences, it is easy to make one using `findnext`:

```
julia> import Base.findall
julia> function findall(pattern,string::AbstractString)
    toReturn = UnitRange{Int64}[]
    s = 1
    while true
        range = findnext(pattern,string,s)
        if range == nothing
             break
        else
            push!(toReturn, range)
            s = first(range)+1
        end
    end
    return toReturn
end

julia> st = "Today is a fresh day: not too warm, not to cold, just fresh!"
"Today is a fresh day: not too warm, not to cold, just fresh!"
julia> ranges = findall("fresh",st)
2-element Array{UnitRange{Int64},1}:
 12:16
 55:59
julia> st2 = "aaffssffssffbbffssffcc"
"aaffssffssffbbffssffcc"
julia> ranges = findall("ffssff",st2)
3-element Array{UnitRange{Int64},1}:
 3:8  
 7:12 
 15:20
julia> ranges = findall("zz",st2)
0-element Array{UnitRange{Int64},1}
```

Replace `s = first(range)+1` with `s = last(range)+1` if you want to account only for full independent patterns.

Comment: Note that something similar should now (Julia 1.3) be available in core..

Answer (score -2):

You can try `contains()` or `search()`.

```
contains(string, substring)

Return a:b, first position, end position
```

or

```
search(string, substring)

Return true or false
```